# How large of a telescope would one need in order to read someone's lips on a planet light years away?

Tags: science-based, planets, space, light

If I wanted to image an Earth-like planet at a resolution where one could read the lips of a human speaking on the surface 1, 10, and 1000 light years away, how large would the telescope reflector need to be (the diameter) in each case?

Another way to ask my question is: Given a parabolic mirror/reflector the size of, say Earth's orbit, what would be the farthest distance one could read someone's lips or read printed text (a secondary concern would be imaging the entire face of the planet at such resolution)?

Assume the telescope is in space (no atmospheric interference) and outside of any asteroid belts or dust clouds, etc. I understand the mirror would have to track the movement of the planet.

My main objective is to get a layman's grasp of the relationship between the size of a telescope's reflector and its ability to see small details very far away. How big of an image can it produce and at what level of detail?

Comment: See the last section of this answer: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/48901/20204 Short answer is "The telescope can't exist" for significant light years away The answer links to this Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2qvna6/eli5_if_i_am_on_a_planet_100_light_years_away/

Comment: Also, is this World Building? This seems to be a pure science/engineering question.

Comment: I read those. They don't seem to address my question. Basically, how far can you see and at what detail given an unlimited mirror size?

Comment: @NexTerren it is WorldBuilding because the Engineering SE seems to shun hypothetical situations as far as I remember (especially those so hypothetical that they will be shoved over here)

Comment: I'd like to know the limits so I can place my world at the proper range ;-)

Comment: @dot_Sp0T But just because it's hypothetical, does that mean it's in-scope here?

Comment: @James Thanks! I hope I'm following the rules. Please let me know if i'm out of line or in the wrong place.

Comment: @NexTerren The links you shared are more concerned with time but seem to conclude (from what I can gather reading through paragraphs of formulas and jargon) that to see 100 light years away at that resolution, you'd need a mirror larger than the size of our solar system, but the explanations are very confusing to the point I'm not sure that single conclusion wasn't just speculation. And I've seen other comments suggesting it could be much smaller. I'm just looking for concrete possibilities (i.e. a telescope with a mirror the size of the moon can read 12pt text 0.1 light years away, etc).

Comment: @AndreiROM, so what are the max limits? I don't care about info lag.

Comment: https://www.metabunk.org/debunked-telescope-distances-of-billions-of-light-years-are-impossible.t7244/ a link that may help you on your journey.  Similar discussion but for an actual telescope being used.

Comment: The question is - do you would really need telescope with lenses or electron telescope?

Comment: See also [How big can we make a telescope?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45756/how-big-can-we-make-a-telescope) — some details in the answers worth reading.

Comment: If I remember correct its impossible due to atmospheric distortion not distance, in orbit around earth looking down still would not work.

Comment: Well, this would be a pretty worthless telescope. Anything you learn is years old, and you can't do much with it. However, you'd want most of your telescope to have an optical zoom, and have digital zoom just as a bonus. Maybe the thing could have a computer algorithm that coupd help determine what's being seen.

Comment: Telescopes make single images from multiple exposures lasting minutes to months. Taking secret video on a far away planet dismisses how telescopes actually work.

Comment: It's not really part of the question, but what's the point of reading lips that spoke years ago?

Answer (score 41):

When talking about telescopes there are two quantities to take into account; the “light gathering power” and the “resolving power” of the telescope.  “Light gathering power” is just how much light can be collected by the telescope.  “Resolving power” is a measure of the smallest angle that the telescope can reliably detect.

Because light is a wave it has a way of spreading out (technically: diffracting).  The smaller the telescope the more the waveness becomes a problem.

What’s a little weird is that this isn’t just limited to the size of the mirror or lens of a single telescope.  By cleverly networking telescopes together you can make them act like a single large telescope.

Visible light has a wavelength of about half a micrometer (one two-millionth of a meter), people are about a meter across (assuming a spherical person), and the Earth is about 13,000,000 meters across.  So, using ground-telescopes that are perfectly constructed and networked, we could spot something person-sized from about 1/400th of a light year away, or about double the distance to Pluto.  For comparison, the distance to the nearest star is about 4 light years.  So, using ground based telescopes we can’t come even remotely close to seeing a person standing around on a planet in another solar system.

The nearest known, reasonable, candidates for being an Earth-like planet (as of April 2013) are about 20 light years away (HD 20794 d, Gliese 581 c, and Gliese 667C c).  Spotting dudes and ladies on one of these worlds requires, at minimum, a telescope array that’s at least 100 million km across.  That’s an array more than half the size of Earth’s orbit.  The good news is that an array like that (under absolutely ideal circumstances) isn’t that difficult to create.  Setting aside that the telescopes would each need to be essentially perfect for their size (Hubble-quality), all we’d need to do is set them up in solar orbits about the size of Earth’s orbit.  This is a lot easier than sending them to another planet, and about as hard as sending them to crash on the Moon.

So, assuming that we could set all that up, the problem stops being one of resolving power, and becomes one of light-gathering power.

On a sunny day we’re hit by about 10^21 (1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000) photons (give or take) every second.  Assuming that a fair fraction of those escape into space, then that number, which seems large, is all that distant aliens have to work with.  Over 20 light years that scant 10^21 photons means you would need a telescope array with an area of more than 500 million square kilometers to catch just one photon per second.  That’s the size of the surface area of Earth.  In the mean time there’s a lot of other light flying around, and single photons are pretty hard to detect so… the signal-to-noise ratio would be small.

Creating an array capable of seeing big stationary things like rivers and mountains on other worlds wouldn’t be too difficult, because you can just use tremendously long exposures to overcome the whole light-gathering issue.  This is a pretty standard trick in astronomy; the Hubble Deep Field took a more than a week of total exposure time.  There would be some issues with the fact that those distant planets are moving and whatnot, but there are clever ways around that too.

People, and probably aliens too, move around a lot.  So if you want to get a picture of one, you need the exposure to take less than, say, a second.  Unless you catch E.T. literally napping.  I would wildly guesstimate that you’d need at least a few thousand photons per second to overcome the signal noise enough to say for certain that you’re looking at something real.

So, to answer a somewhat more detailed question; to get a picture of an alien that’s person-sized, standing on a world 20 light years away, so that it takes up one pixel in the image, using an exposure time of about one second, would require an array of telescopes with exposed mirrors and lenses with an area totaling more than several thousand times the Earth’s surface area and spread out over a region about the size of Earth’s orbit.

This isn’t technically impossible, but it would be “expensive”, and would require substantially more materials than are likely to be reasonably found in our solar system.  It probably isn’t worth it to get a blurry, tiny picture of some alien picking its nose 20 light years away and 20 years ago.

Of course, if you wanted to see farther, you’d need a much larger telescope array.

Comment: Also there are other things to take into account such as atmosphere thickness (i.e. clouds), planets being aligned correctly, dust clouds in space, and anything that could cause a blockage or distortion of the light from planet A to B such as gravity beasts like Black Holes etc.

Comment: Exposure time! I wasn't thinking in those terms. That "sheds some light" on my thought process. Thanks!

Comment: Also rain, local pollution from cars etc, remember nothing is impossible just very hard, someone once laughed about having metal ships, flying metal tin cans (aircraft), even going into space, if you are using advanced technology rather than just a standard telescope like today then as long as you have a feasible reason why your advanced telescope can do what it claims thats all good :)

Comment: So given an array the size of Earth's orbit, how far away do you think one could read text on a sheet of paper (or on the side of a spaceship)?

Comment: yes, I'm actually counting on rain and pollution and clouds and planet rotation to obscure most observations. Even current Earth spy satellites have to deal with that! :-)

Comment: Since the biggest problem is gathering light, I suggest using supernovas as flash lights. Of course, you'll need to predict when are they going to happen, but it can't be harder than building such enormous telescopes.

Comment: @Sandy no tech will ever be able to see photons that aren't there. So it wouldn't be light - based, and thus I wouldn't call that "seeing".

Comment: Good analysis that points to the impossibility of the request.

Comment: 1021 and 10^21 are not the same thing.

Comment: Good answer. Regarding your notation about black holes distorting the light, that is actually more likely to help than to ruin the attempt as it might act as a [gravitational lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens)

Comment: You didn’t explain **how you computed** the needed size of the synthetic aperture.  You just stated that it’s about 1 AU in radius.

Comment: Would the light of the target planet's star outshine the planet, leaving it too dark to see the surface in detail (if your telescope is so sensitive as to gather the light of a planet's surface...) and/or just blind your scope with too much light?

Comment: Another problem.  Your telescope is 6 light-minutes across.  That means the light hitting the camera is spread over 3 minutes (actually, somewhat more, as it's not coplanar with the mirrors) and this will blur the image the same as a 3 minute time exposure.  Thus you're not seeing aliens walking around any more than 3 minute shot here on Earth would show people walking around.

Comment: @LorenPechtel A parabolic mirror as the primary reflector will solve that problem.

Answer (score 27):

#### TL;DR: Depending on the fidelity of video you want to shoot of the aliens, you can be limited either by diffraction (low fidelity) or photon counting (high fidelity). Overall, the numbers are really large though. For example, the telescope radius for doing lip reading at a distance of 1 lightyear (~ 63000 AU) is roughly ∼92 AU (!). With a 1 AU telescope, you can do lip reading for folks ~700 AU far away.

## Key result

To shoot video that resolves a length scale of $d_\alpha$ at $60 \text{ fps}$ with decent color accuracy (8-bit RGB, error rate < 1/10)
when the alien star is sun-like and the system is at a distance $\ell$ from the telescope, 
the telescope radius $r$ is bounded below due to photon counting considerations by:

$$ r_{\text{min}} \simeq \frac{\ell}{2d_\alpha} (7.27\times 10^{-6}\text{ m}).$$

If one relaxes the demands on the video fidelity, the limiting factor becomes the diffraction of red light:

$$ r_{\text{min}} \simeq \frac{\ell}{2d_\alpha} (6.20\times 10^{-7}\text{ m}).$$

## Answers

> If I wanted to image an Earth-like planet at a resolution where one could read the lips of a human speaking on the surface 1, 10, and 1000 light years away, how large would the telescope reflector need to be (the diameter) in each case?

Say we want to do lip reading. The size of a human mouth is about $5\text{ cm} = 0.05\text{ m}$. Suppose we assume that if we have a video where your mouth is about 20 pixels wide, we can reasonably do lip reading (the vertical direction has the same scale so no worries that lips will look too thin). Then $d_\alpha = 0.05/20 = 0.0025\text{ m} =2.5\text{ mm}$. So for the first question, the telescope *radius* for doing lip reading at distance of $\ell = 1 \text{ lightyear}$ is roughly (using the first formula) $1.4\times 10^{13}\text{ m} \sim 92\text{ AU}$. For comparison, the radius of Neptune's orbit is about $30 \text{ AU}$. So our telescope has to be really big!

> Another way to ask my question is: Given a parabolic mirror/reflector the size of, say Earth's orbit, what would be the farthest distance one could read someone's lips or read printed text (a secondary concern would be imaging the entire face of the planet at such resolution)?

One can similarly answer the second question. For that, you plug in the telescope size $r = 1\text{ AU} = 1.5\times 10^{11}\text{ m}$ and the same $d_\alpha = 2.5\text { mm}$ as before. This gives the distance to be $\ell \sim 10^{14}\text{ m} \sim 700\text{ AU}$. You can see that this is about 23 times the radius of Neptune's orbit.

Imaging the full planet at this resolution is not an issue -- all we are doing is replacing a small telescope (like the Hubble) with a huge telescope. This does not decrease our field of view (physical size represented by picture) but it does enhance the resolution (sharpness of picture) and imaging fidelity (correctness of picture).

> My main objective is to get a layman's grasp of the relationship between the size of a telescope's reflector and its ability to see small details very far away. How big of an image can it produce and at what level of detail?

You can tweak the level of detail and image size (I assume you mean pixels) by adjusting the parameter $d_\alpha$ by considering the following: imagine a digital photograph of the object you want to actually image. Calculate the appropriate $d_\alpha$ by dividing the physical length of the object by the minimum width of the "imaginary digital photo" (in pixels) at which the object is clearly identifiable. Basically, $d_\alpha$ is the physical size corresponding to 1 pixel width.

## Cosmic videography theory (CVT)

### Pursuit - Speed, color and pixels

Suppose we want to shoot the video with a minimum time-scale of $\delta t$. 
For example, if you want to shoot slow-mo at $200 \text{ fps}$ then use 
$\delta t = 1/200 {\text{ s}}$. We would like to record RGB values on a linear 
scale with 256 divisions, where each channel is defined by a pair $(\lambda_X,\epsilon_X)$ 
($X=R,G,B$).

The ease of resolution will depend on how small of a background you have. 
This is common sense -- you can see many stars at night and only the sun during the day.
For simplicity (and best performance), assume that our sun, telescope and alien 
are in a straight line (in that order). We put stuff between the sun and the 
telescope to (effectively) block out all the radiation from the sun. 
For example, you can use lead blocks to block $\gamma$ rays etc.
In principle, it is possible to have zero background if your resolution
is good enough and your detectors have no noise of their own 
(super chilled, superconducting, super everything) so let's stick with that.

You can get rid of the background but you cannot get rid of [Rayleigh's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution). 
Let the diameter of the alien subject be $d_\alpha$, the radius of our 
Peeping Tom Telescope Array (PTTA) be $r$ and the distance to the alien 
subject be $\ell$.

$$ \frac{d_\alpha}{\ell} = \theta \geq \frac{\lambda_R}{2 r} \implies
  r \geq \frac{\lambda_R \ell}{2 d_\alpha}$$

where we used $\lambda_R$ as it is the largest wavelength out of the three
and hence needs the largest PTTA.

As pointed out in @SandyBeach's nice 
[answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/70700/37356),
we need to consider both resolution and exposure. We have already 
discussed resolution, we now proceed to counting photons.

### Intro - Photon generation and redirection

Definitions: power = energy per unit time, intensity = power per unit area, 
intensity spectrum = intensity per unit wavelength, 
flux = number per unit time,
flux density = flux per unit area, 
flux density spectrum = flux density per unit wavelength.

The intensity spectrum $dI(\lambda)/d\lambda$ of the alien's sun is given by Planck's law;
we can use this to get the flux density spectrum $d \sigma_\Phi(\lambda)/d\lambda$ 
using $I = E(\lambda) \sigma_\Phi = hc \sigma_\Phi/\lambda $ for photons:

$$\frac{d P(\lambda)}{d \lambda} = \frac{2 hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{\exp\left[\frac{hc}{\lambda k_B T}\right]-1} 
\implies 
\frac{d \sigma_\Phi(\lambda)}{d \lambda} = \frac{2 c}{\lambda^4}\frac{1}{\exp\left[\frac{hc}{\lambda k_B T}\right]-1}$$

The total flux density is $\Sigma_\Phi = \int_0^\infty \frac{d\sigma_\Phi(\lambda)}{d\lambda} d \lambda$. Similarly the fraction of 
flux density in a window of wavelengths $(\lambda-\epsilon,\lambda+\epsilon)$ will be

$$f(\lambda, \epsilon) = \frac{1}{\Sigma_\Phi} \int_{\lambda-\epsilon}^{\lambda+\epsilon} \frac{d\sigma_\Phi(\lambda')}{d\lambda'} d\lambda'.$$

Suppose the subject of our video is illuminated by a star and has a response function $\alpha(\lambda)\geq 0$, i.e., 
if the incident flux is $\Phi(\lambda)$ then the outgoing flux is omnidirectional (to first approximation) 
with magnitude $\alpha(\lambda)\Phi(\lambda)$. Assuming that the subject is not on fire, $\alpha(\lambda)\leq 1$.
If the subject is blue in the face, then $\alpha(450\text{ nm})\simeq 1$ and $\alpha(600\text{ nm})\simeq 0$. 
If the subject is a mango, then $\alpha(450\text{ nm})\simeq 0$ and $\alpha(600\text{ nm})\simeq 1$.

**Note:** We ignore atmospheric effects (on the alien planet) which may alter the spectrum in a [nontrivial manner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#/media/File:Spectrum_of_Sunlight_en.svg).

### Incident - Poisson statistics

In an ideal scenario, the RGB values recorded would correspond directly to 
$\alpha(\lambda_X)$. For example, if the scale is from 0 to 255, then we 
would (ideally) record R=0 if $\alpha(\lambda_R) \leq 1/256$, B=255 
if $\alpha(\lambda_B) \geq 255/256$ and so on.
However, the minimum of the three $f(\lambda_X,\epsilon_X)$ values is a bottleneck for 
measurement. Why? Since our fluxes may be small, we must apply [Poisson 
statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_statistics) instead of taking 
a uniform flux. The flux density of the star 
$f(\lambda_X,\epsilon_X)\Sigma_\Phi$ is related to the incident flux 
on the alien subject by a wavelength-independent geometric factor, say $Z$, so 
$\Phi(\lambda_X) = Z f(\lambda_X,\epsilon_X)\Sigma_\Phi$. 
Then the expected flux in channel $X$ in the time $\delta t$ will be

$$\mu(\lambda_X) = \delta t\cdot Z_T \alpha(\lambda_X) Z f(\lambda_X,\epsilon_X)\Sigma_\Phi$$

where $Z_T = \pi r^2/(4\pi \ell^2) = r^2/4 \ell^2$ is an additional geometric factor and (like before)
$r$ is the radius of the PTTA and $\ell$ is distance from the PTTA to the subject.

The probability of getting a count of $k$ will be

$$P_X(k) = \frac{\mu(\lambda_X)^k e^{-\mu(\lambda_X)}}{k!}\quad k = 0, 1, 2,\ldots$$

As long as the subject is not too dark (i.e. small $\alpha$ for all $\lambda_X$), we can 
approximate the Poisson distribution by a Gaussian of mean $\mu(\lambda_X)$ and standard deviation 
$\sqrt{\mu(\lambda_X)}$:

$$P'_X(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \mu(\lambda_X)}} \exp\left[-\frac{(x-\mu(\lambda_X))^2}{2\mu(\lambda_X)}\right]$$

[image: Fit of Gaussian distribution to Poisson distribution]

Graph showing fit of Gaussian (line) to Poisson distribution for mean values $64,128$ and $256$.

### Reasoning - The Measurement Process

Let us now discuss the actual measurement process.
Naively, one would think that $\mu$ should at least be $256$ for 
$\alpha = 1$ so that the full color range of 0-255 is used. 
In a time step $\delta t$, count the photons and assign the value 
to the corresponding color. However, the counting statistics make this complicated. 
For example, if $\alpha = 0.5 \leftrightarrow \mu=128$, it is 
quite possible that the actual counts observed in successive time steps 
will look like {120, 133, 131, 125, 134} (because the Gaussian standard 
deviation is $8\sqrt{2}$) and therefore the $\alpha$ value
will be incorrect at all the five time steps. ☹

#### Special Investigation - A quest for better color reproduction

Suppose we have a tolerance $p$ for errors ($0<p<1$), i.e., at most $Np$ out of $N$ measurements are incorrect.
We demand that this condition holds separately for each bin from B=0 to B=255 and similarly for G and R.
Without loss of generality, let the alien's sun have $f(\lambda_B,\epsilon_B)$ as the least value 
out of the three. For simplicity, let $m=\mu(\lambda_B)$ when $a(\lambda_B)=1$, so $m$ is the maximum number of 
"blue photons" received in an interval $\delta t$ (as $a(\lambda)\leq 1$).

As shown above, it is clear that having the value $m = 256$ will not satisfy $p<1$ as most results will be 
erroneous. Therefore, $m$ has to be much larger than $256$. In that case, the B value as a function of 
count $n_B$ is set using

$$ B(n_B) = \begin{cases}
            \mathrm{floor}(256 n_B/m) & 0\leq n_B < m \\
            255 & n_B \geq m
            \end{cases}
            $$

(We will account for the error due to the truncation in our simulation.)

Using a larger average value will reduce our relative error:

[image: Peak narrowing.]

This graph shows the reducing rate of error as $m$ is increased ($m=2^9, 2^{10},2^{11}$). 
Each individual peak shows the probability density of some actual B value being mistaken 
for another B value; the larger the spread, the higher the chances of error. 
The relative error for the Gaussian scales as $1/\sqrt{m}$ 
(the standard deviation scales slower than the mean) which is reflected in the 
thinner peaks for larger $m$.

One way to numerically find a suitable value of $m$ is to use [Monte Carlo simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method).
The basic idea is described in pseudocode below:

```
poisson_to_gaussian_cutoff = 15

function right_wrong(m, n_runs):
    right = array(elem = 0, length = 256)
    wrong = array(elem = 0, length = 256)
    A = random_number_array(uniform_dist(0,1), length = n_runs)
    B = []
    for a in A :
        if a >= poissonToGaussianCutoff / m :
            B.append(256/m * random_number(gaussian_dist(mean = m*a, stdev = sqrt(m*a))))
        else :
            B.append(256/m * random_number(poisson_dist(mean = m*a)))
    for (b,a') in zip(B, floor(256 * A)):
        # array numbering begins at zero
        if (0 <= b <= 255 and b == a'):
            right[b] += 1
        else if (0 <= b <= 255 and b != a'):
            wrong[b] += 1
        else if (b < 0 and a' == 0):
            right[0] += 1
        else if (b < 0 and a' != 0):
            wrong[0] += 1
        else if (b > 255 and a' == 255):
            right[255] += 1
        else if (b > 255 and a' != 255):
            wrong[255] += 1
    return (right, wrong)

M = [256, 512, 1024, ...] # candidate m values to test
N_runs = 2^20             # seems to work well
binwise_p_list = []
for m in M:
    mright, mwrong = right_wrong(m, N_runs)
    binwise_p_list.append(mwrong / mright) # element-wise division
```

We plot $p$ values for each bin for different choices of $m$.

[image: Color accuracy - counting rate]

For a value of $p=0.1$, $m=2^{22}$ is okay. For super-duper high quality at $p=0.01$, 
$m=2^{28}$ is reasonable (although it is kind of hard to see in the graph).

### Action - Numbers

Let's stick with $p=0.1$ so $m=2^{22}$. For a smooth viewing experience, we demand 
$\delta t\leq 1/60\text{ s}$ ($\geq 60\text{ fps}$). The value for $f(\lambda_B,\epsilon_B)$ 
can be found using numerical integration. I could not find a good way to fix the values of 
the wavelength windows so I've set them as: $\lambda_B = 450 \text{ nm}$,
$\lambda_G = 530 \text{ nm}$, $\lambda_R = 620\text{ nm}$ and 
$\epsilon_B = \epsilon_G = \epsilon_R = 40\text{ nm}$ (roughly based off the table in Ref 1.).
For a sun-like star ($T=5772 \text{ K}$), the values of $f$ and $\Sigma_\Phi$ are

$$ f_B = 0.0491401,\,f_G = 0.0593743,\,f_R = 0.0634818\text{ and } \Sigma_\Phi = 9.281\times 10^{25} \text{ m}^{-2}\text{s}^{-1}.$$

Since the value of $f_B$ is the lowest, we will use it. (We also used $f_B$ in the preceding discussion.)

For a subject chilling at about $1.008 \text{ AU}$ and the alien sun having radius equal to $R_\odot$, we 
have the geometric factor

$$Z = \pi d_\alpha^2/4 \left[\frac{R_\odot^2}{1.008 \text{ AU}}\right]^2 = 1.67\times 10^{-5}d_\alpha^2$$

where $d_\alpha$ is (like before) the diameter of the alien subject.

We assume that the typical value of $\alpha(\lambda_X)\sim 1$; we found out the $m$ value(s) using this.
(Otherwise, we *could* rescale $m$ somehow to account for the maximum achievable $\alpha(\lambda_X)\ll 1$...)

We put everything together, recalling that $m$ is the *lower* limit for $\mu(\lambda_X)$:

$$\mu(\lambda_X) \leq \delta t\cdot Z_T \alpha(\lambda_X) Z f(\lambda_X,\epsilon_X)\Sigma_\Phi $$
$$m \leq \delta t \frac{r^2}{4\ell^2}\cdot 1.67\times 10^{-5} d_\alpha^2 \cdot 0.0491\cdot 9.281\times 10^{25}$$
$$ r \geq \frac{\ell}{2 d_\alpha}\sqrt{\frac{16\cdot 2^{22}}{(1/60)\cdot 1.67\times10^{-5}\cdot 0.0491\cdot 9.281\times 10^{25}}}$$
$$ r \geq \frac{\ell}{2d_\alpha} (7.27\times 10^{-6}\text{ m}) $$

This expression is an order of magnitude higher than the resolving-power based expression which has $\lambda_R \sim 6\times 10^{-7} \text{ m}$ 
instead of $7.27\times 10^{-6}\text{ m}$.

Let us do some quick sanity checks for the numbers:

1. The total flux density incident on the subject if it were Earth-sized ($d_\alpha = 12600 \text{ km}$) would be

   $$\frac{\Sigma_\Phi \times Z}{\pi d_\alpha^2/4} \sim 10^{26} \cdot 1.6 \times 10^{-5} \cdot (4/\pi) \sim 2\times 10^{21} \text{ m}^{-2}\text{s}^{-1}$$ 
   which agrees with the standard number up to order of magnitude (also present in @SandyBeach's answer).
2. Consider putting a $1\text{ cm}\times 1\text{ cm}$ plate of aluminium coated with [Vantablack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack), one of the darkest materials known, in the sun (here on Earth). The number of photons *reflected* by it in a time of $1/60 \text{ s}$ will be $10^{21} \cdot 0.01\cdot 0.01 \cdot 1/60 \cdot 0.00035 \sim 6 \times 10^{11}$. This number is still very big relative to the figure we obtained for $p=0.01$, $m = 2^{28} \sim 2.7\times 10^8$.
3. The values of $f_X \sim 0.06$ are not too shabby given that the solar spectrum peaks at . I think that the value for red is higher than green because one has to multiply the intensity spectrum by $\lambda/hc$ to get the flux density spectrum, thereby red-shifting the peak of the distribution.

#### Horror - Low accuracy, low speed attempted compromise

If we set $p = 0.6$ (for R=0,...,128, not for all R=0,...,255), we can get away with $m = 2^{17}$.

[image: Compromise plot]

We reduce the framerate to a crawling $1 \text{ fps}$. If we try to scale up $\Sigma_\Phi$, 
the planet will move further away and $Z$ will decrease in order to avoid cooking the alien. 
With these new parameters, we have
$$ r \geq \frac{\ell}{2d_\alpha} \frac{(7.27\times 10^{-6}\text{ m})}{\sqrt{2^5 60}} =  \frac{\ell}{2d_\alpha} (1.66\times 10^{-7}\text{ m}).$$

So if you try to degrade the "stream" quality by too much then you are limited by diffraction, not photon counting.

### Suspicion - Something *feels* off

1. The wavelength calculations are wrong because the light will be blue-shifted/red-shifted.

   Well, the relative speed of the alien subject to its own star is much less than $c$. You are right 
   about the light being Doppler shifted. That just changes what kind of detector is used and does 
   not affect our calculations.

### Dirge - References

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum#Spectral_colors

Comment: This went into more detail than my puny human brain can understand. I got some numbers at the end (of the first section) that were staggeringly large and had to smile and nod.

Comment: @Draco18s, I made the simplest model I could to derive the numbers from first principles and minimize arbitrary guesses. I did not intend for the answer to be intimidating.... If I started to explain all the details like the integration, Planck's law, statistics etc. then the answer would've become twice as long, so I chose to avoid that. :-/

Comment: Your answers are incredible. +1 from me and again, good to have you on board!

Comment: Results indeed seems off, and I'd like to see this figured out, but you gave really solid foundation for this. Also, could you **please highlight the actual sizes**, as a summary on the beginning or the end, for people who can't understand all the math or simply don't have time or patience to do it? That way your answer will be less intimidating with no harm to accuracy.

Comment: is "dα=0.05 m" really correct? that may be about mouth-sized, but wouldn't that make the mouth (or a squarish area around the mouth) one pixel? Aka, definitely NOT fine enough to read lips, which requires seeing the lip configuration (open, closed, pursed...)?

Comment: @Mołot, I've added some sanity checks. There are some numbers in the Answers section at the beginning. What other numbers would you like to see?

Comment: @Syndic, you are right. I've made the correction. I was thinking about McPixel for some reason when I wrote that.

Comment: @Mołot, turns out I made a calculation mistake in the "Answers". Sorry! If someone could just double-check the calculation I've given under "Answers", that'd be awesome. I've gotten it wrong twice already :(

Comment: I didn't meant other numbers. I meant ∼92 AU in first line, so it would catch the eye first. Just a minor layout suggestion., that's all.

Comment: @Mołot, good point! The punchline should be in the TL;DR. Fixed.

Comment: @theindigamer No no, good answer. Its just that my eyes glazed over after the first couple of paragraphs. XD

Comment: All the answers so far are over-complicating the exposure calculation. People are extended objects, as in terrestrial photography. Once you've calculated the focal length you need to get your target to cover the appropriate number of pixels, then if you know the f-ratio you need for your desired frame rate, then you can work out the needed diameter for the exposure by dividing the focal length by the needed f-ratio. You don't have to change exposure depending on how far away things are - distance x 2 => photon flux/4 -but it also quarters the area in the image so photons/unit area is the same.

Comment: @JerryTheC, I think you are right on most points. Since I actually started writing my answer in an attempt to figure out SandyBeach's arbitrary figure of ~1000 photons/sec, I've modeled the telescope in a similar manner; the "zoom" depends on the distance so that an object of given size takes a fixed number of pixels. OTOH, what I think you are saying is that the size of the image in pixels gets smaller as the object moves further away (which is what happens if you don't zoom in). So I think we are modeling the telescope differently...I'm not sure how to do the calculation you've described...

Comment: The image scale depends on the focal length (and the resolution depends on the diameter).  Once you've worked out the minimum diameter to resolve the level of detail you need, you then need to work out the image scale that you'll need to get your target to cover the required number of pixels on your sensor. Individual pixel size is determined by your sensor choice. The image scale (usually measured in arcseconds/pixel for astro use) is determined by the focal length of your optics. Bigger focals lengths give a bigger image scale - the image of the target covers a larger area,,,,

Comment: ... and smaller focal lengths give a smaller image of the target. Because you're spreading the same amount of input light out, the smaller image is brighter than the bigger one, since the f-ratio (focal length divided by diameter) is faster (smaller number). So work out the required image scale (and/or) arcseconds/pixel needed, which will let you work out the required focal length. Then divide the focal length by the diameter to get your f-ratio. If that's not fast enough for your video, you can divide the focal length by the needed f-ratio to work out how big a mirror is needed to get there.

Comment: arcseconds/pixel = (pixel size in micro metres / focal length in mm) * 206.3

Comment: @JerryTheC, I think I kind of follow the explanation, but not fully... Why don't you submit an answer with the calculation done using your method? I'd love to see how the numbers compare. I would also like to see how you model the color accuracy bit, amongst other things.

Comment: "For example, the telescope radius for doing lip reading at a distance of 1 lightyear (~ 63000 AU) is roughly ∼92 AU (!). With a 1 AU telescope, you can do lip reading for folks ~700 AU far away." So what you're saying is that a telescope can see 700 times as far as it's own size if the requirement is about 1 pixel/cm²? That is disappointing result. So with a mouth sized lens (Ø5 cm) you should be able to barely read lips from 35m away?

Comment: @Herman there are lots of assumptions going in. If my fidelity requirement is too high, you could get roughly an order of magnitude improvement. But the diffraction limit is a hard one, so the ratio can't be improved beyond ~8000.

Comment: What  can I say but... dang.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/83803/60040), you'd need a telescope, the size of "the Hubble space telescope" to read the numbers on a licence plate or recognise someones face on the distance of 10km.

So I guess, you need a telescope, the size of a planet, or even bigger to achieve what you want.
Even if you have your telescope in space, the other person is almost certainly on a planet with an atmosphere (if you want to keep track of the planet and read lips), it is almost impossible (see the link above) to see anything. Maybe you have the biggest chance trying to do this at dawn. You also want to consider weather on your chosen target planet.

Maybe an altered version of the deathstar will do the trick.

By the way such telescopes usually don't come with autofocus and people tend to move a lot.

You also have to consider, that light bends (around large objects, like stars and planets).
Having a lot of moving parts in space and a distance of 10 light years, will probably make it pretty hard to keep track of your target, because a slight wobble close to the origin light source, will have a giant influence on the other end.

As a sidenote, you might also want to consider how you treat close light sources, that will "over expose" your image.

Update

To see the same for twice the distance, you neet to double the zoom.
According to photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13717/…, you can calculate zoom from focal-length, from a given lens (in our case we take the HST specifications).
The [HST hat a focal lenght of 57.6m](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble-Weltraumteleskop) and can see with the mentioned resolution 10km.
For one lightyear, that would give you a focal length of 5.472 * 10^13m. The earth has a diameter of 12'742 km.
The (mid-) Distance from Sun and Saturn is according to [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6%C3%9Fenordnung_(L%C3%A4nge)) 1.427 * 10^12m.
So the focal length is about thirty eight times the distance of the solar system.
To keep the f-stop of f/22 of Hubble, that would make a lens diameter of 2.487 * 10^12m. Which is still 1.7 Times the distance from Sun to Saturn.

These Calculations, however are for lenses, [Hubble doesn’t have a lens. Like all large telescopes, Hubble uses a curved mirror to focus starlight. This mirror is located deep inside the telescope.](https://www.spacetelescope.org/about/faq/)

You might want to protect this precious piece from asteroids.

You can do the Math for 10 and 100 lightyears.

Comment: A wild guess?  No real knowledge or calculation?

Comment: I'm referencing the mentioned source, with the calcilation.

Comment: That gives the resolution of HST.  How do you get “size of a planet or bigger” for the answer?

Comment: That's much better!  Your “update” is really what should be the answer, beyond the first paragraph.  Do you see how what you wrote now is quantitatively different from the original?  The original (after the first paragraph) goes off on irrelevant tangents and only has one sentence of Answer.  I'd suggest deleting those old paragraphs.